# PHP Merging two arrays and combining the different values for both, array merge doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays

I am wanting to merge 2 arrays that may or may not share the same values, and may or may not have the same keys.

If a key exist in both arrays, I want to merge both values. If a key doesn't exist in the other, I want to add it to the array, adding the missing key/value.

In the below example, `Array A` and `Array B` share a common `user_key`.

But `Array A` has a `taken_count` KVP, and `Array B` has `release_count` KVP.

I want a new array that uses the `user_key` KVP as the array key. If a KVP exists in one array but not the other, I want to add it to the `user_key'.

You can see that user 1111 is in both arrays, so his `user_name`, `taken_count` and `release_count` is added to the new array.

Person B doesn't exist in Array B, so person B's is added to the new array and the `release_count` KVP is added with 0

Same for C.

I have tried multiple variations on array_merge_recursive, but it doesn't add the missing keys.

I use the below `foreach` to loop through all the calls released then I use another `foreach` that loops through all the taken. But some KVPs are missing.

```
foreach ($calls_released_by_user as $key=>$value){
        $user_name     = array_key_exists($key, $calls_taken_by_user) ? $calls_taken_by_user[$key]['user_name']  : 0
        $taken_count   = array_key_exists($key, $calls_taken_by_user) ? $calls_taken_by_user[$key]['taken_count']  : 0;
        $release_count = array_key_exists($key, $calls_released_by_user)  ?  $calls_released_by_user[$key]['release_count'] : 0;


        $all_user_calls_counts[$key] =  array(  'user_name'=>$value['user_name'],
                                                'taken_count' => $taken_count,
                                                'release_count' => $release_count);


    }
```

ARRAY A

```
[0]=>
{
    ["user_key"]    =>   "1111"    
    ["user_name"]   =>  "A Person"
    ["taken_count"] =>   "10"
}
[1]=>
{
    ["user_key"]    =>  "2222"    
    ["user_name"]   =>  "B Person"
    ["taken_count"] =>   "20"
}
```

ARRAY B

```
[0]=>
{
    ["user_key"]        => "1111"    
    ["user_name"]       => "A Person"
    ["release_count"]   => "5"
}
[1]=>
{
    ["user_key"]        => "3333"    
    ["user_name"]       => "C Person"
    ["release_count"]   => "50"
}
```

COMBINED ARRAYS USING USER_KEY AS THE NEW KEY

```
[1111]=>
   {
    ["user_name"]       => "A Person"
    ["release_count"]   => "5"
    ["taken_count"]     => "10"
  }
  [2222]=>
  {
    ["user_name"]       => "B Person"
    ["taken_count"]     => "20"
    ["release_count"]   => "0"
  }
   [3333]=>
  {
    ["user_name"]       => "C Person"
    ["taken_count"]     => "0"
    ["release_count"]   => "50"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`array_key_exists($key, $calls_taken_by_user)` is not correct. This checks for the array index in the other array, but the two arrays don't have elements that correspond by index.

You should convert the second array into an associative array that's keyed by `user_key`. Then you can easily search for matching elements between the two arrays and merge them.

```
$assoc_calls_taken = [];
foreach ($calls_taken_by_user as $el) {
    $assoc_calls_taken[$el['user_id']] = $el;
}

foreach ($calls_released_by_user as $el) {
    $user = $el['user_key'];
    $all_user_calls_counts[$user] = $el;
    $all_user_calls_counts[$user]['release_count'] = isset($assoc_calls_take[$user])) ? $$assoc_calls_take[$user]['release_count']) : 0;
}
```

Comment: You would have to also go through the `calls_taken` array to get all the users that appeared there but not in the `calls_relased`. Now in `all_users_calls_counts` you will only have users that appeared in the `calls_released` array.

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate both arrays one after another:

```
$all_user_calls_counts = [];
foreach ($calls_taken_by_user as $taken) {
    $all_user_calls_counts[$taken['user_key']] = [
        'user_name'     => $taken['user_name'],
        'taken_count'   => $taken['taken_count'],
        'release_count' => '0'
    ];
}

foreach ($calls_released_by_user as $released) {
    $key = $released['user_key'];
    if (isset($all_user_calls_counts[$key])) {
        $all_user_calls_counts[$key]['release_count'] = $released['release_count'];
        continue;
    }
    $all_user_calls_counts[$key] = [
        'user_name'     => $released['user_name'],
        'taken_count'   => '0',
        'release_count' => $released['release_count']
    ];
}
```

You can make code more readable with array destructuring (assign fields to variables in one command), but I don't know which php version you use.